# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException For String

Tags: java, spring, mockito

Any thoughts on how can I fix this problem

Method threw 'org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.abc.ykservice.core.service.YkService$MockitoMock$2027295763.toString()

```
@Test
    public void testMethod() {
        YkService ykService = Mockito.mock(YkService.class);
        String year = "2017";
        Mockito.when(ykService.31GetCalYear())
                .thenReturn(year); // ***The exception is shown at this line*** 
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = ykServiceController.yk31();
        Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
        Assert.assertEquals("2017", responseEntity.getBody());
    }
```

The Ykservice is an interface defining the below method which is implemented in another class
    String 31GetCalYear();

I cant use the mock the YKservice for the whole class because there are other tests using this YKservice in the non mock mode ..

Comment: ykServiceController is a mock or a real object ? If it's a mock, it may explain the error...

Comment: Can you please confirm that YkService is `public` and non-`final`, and that `31GetCalYear()` is `public`, non-`static`, and non-`final`?

Comment: The ykServicecontroller is a real object which has been autowired in this class and am trying to test a rest end point yk31() ...

Comment: YkService is an interface n it's public n non-final ..and 31GetCalYear() is non-static and implicitly declared public..

Comment: @jenny,  did you find the solution? I am also facing the same issue.